# How to set SKU for each attribute value in configurable product in Magento 1.7?

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7, e-commerce

I am working on creating an online Clothing Store. I have different item codes for a same product by its attributes: I listed my products here.

```
Item Code    Item Name Size    Case Quantity Color
---------    --------- ----    ------------ -----
12S          Foam Cup  8 oz    40/25        white
13S          Foam Cup  10 oz   40/25        white
14S          Foam Cup  12 oz   40/25        white
15S          Foam Cup  16 oz   40/25        white
```

When  a customer buys a product **Foam Cup  16 oz -  40/25  -    white** then the **SKU** should be **15S**. How can I create a configurable product like this? How to set attributes in **Manage Attributes** and **Attribute set** to accomplish like this ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do like this :

1. Create a new attribute which name is "Size".
   when creating this attirbute, you must choose the configurable option.
2. Create a configurable product: c_product
   when creating a new product, you might choose the configurable attribute. In this page, please select the Size option.
3. Creates 4 simple products which the sku code are 12s, 13s, 14s and 15s.
   Of course, this product should have also size attribute.
4. Please add those 4 products to the configurable product.
   Manage product-> choose that configurable product -> Associated Products tab.
   Find out those products and click the checkbox and, it will add the size option automatically in Super product attributes configuration section.

Answer (score 0):

i had a similar productstructure.

For this is i used individual options.

First create the Article Foam Cup, add the attributes Case Quantity and Color.
Then add the Sizes to your custom options.

cheers!